# Android: How to style for a link in file string.xml?

Tags: android, css, xml, hyperlink

I have created a custom dialog with some information about app. one of them is a hyperlink with text get from `string.xml` file, content like this:

```
<string name="copyright">Bản quyền © 2014 thuộc 
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/nguyen.ngochoang.758" style="text-   decoration:none;">Nguyễn Ngọc Hoàng</a></string>
```

It work Ok, but the hyperlink has an underline. So, how can i style for the link with some css like above, in my code.

Comment: hi answer is updated, have a look!!

Comment: you don't want underline??. You can use spannable string for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Hi use given below properly formatted lines

```
   <string name="copyright">Bản quyền © 2014 thuộc 
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/nguyen.ngochoang.758"  style="text-decoration:none;">Nguyễn Ngọc Hoàng</a></string>
```

i checked at http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_linknoline and is working fine, please copy given lines and paste at given web link and check, it will work fine!!

Comment: are you sure style attribute is supported in strings.xml??

Comment: will need to check document again, please have a look there!!

Comment: i don't think style attribute is supported

Comment: yes it looks like there is no support, i am checking extensively!! i think op should use a string asset at asset folder rather than strings.xml than